# Can ampersand be used to print a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

Didn't really know how to title this question.

Consider an arbitrary hash (ENV is convenient):

```
ENV.each { |key, val| puts key + ': ' + val }
LC_MESSAGES: en_US.utf-8
LC_COLLATE: en_US.utf-8
PWD: /Users/baller/ive_fallen_and_i_cant_get_up
LC_MONETARY: en_US.utf-8
```

Is it possible to use the &: shorthand to do this?

```
foo.each(&:bar)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get away with two block variables and have one instead by doing this:

```
each{|kv| puts kv.join(": ")}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, no.

To do what you want, you would need to add a method to the Array class, which prints out the way you want, something like:

```
class Array
  def bar
    puts "#{self[0]}: #{self[1]}"
  end
end
```

with that, `ENV.each(&:bar)` will do what you expect.

That said, I would not recommend this. Adding to a base class is something that should only be done when the utility far outweighs the potential for future conflicts, and the fact that this method is highly specialized for arrays with at least 2 elements in them.

Not related, but concatenating strings via `+` is measurably slower than using interpolation. It creates extra objects unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, using `&:bar` in place of a block will result in `#to_proc` being called on the given object, in this case, the symbol `:bar`. The `#to_proc` implementation of Symbol in Ruby basically expands `foo.each(&:bar)` to `foo.each { |i| i.bar }`. Since there are two arguments yielded from a hash, `i` in this example is an array of the key, value args. This is why you'd have to extend `Array` (as described by @x1a4) to get your hash to treat &:bar as expected.

As an alternative, you can create your own class that responds to `#to_proc` or simply implement your block as a Proc:

```
class Bar
  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |key, val| puts key + ': ' + val }
  end
end

bar = Bar.new

# or

bar = Proc.new { |key, val| puts key + ': ' + val }
```

With a handle to bar, you can pass &bar in place of a block to hashes like ENV. So given a hash, foo:

```
foo.each(&bar)
```

A great post for more reading on this subject: http://weblog.raganwald.com/2008/06/what-does-do-when-used-as-unary.html

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is possible if the elements of the collection respond to that method. For example:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar

  def initialize(bar)
    @bar = bar
  end
end

foos = [Foo.new("one"), Foo.new("two"), Foo.new("three")]

p foos.map(&:bar)  #=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```

This works because `&symbol` is syntactic sugar for [`symbol.to_proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc), which in turn works some magic to return a block that sends that message to the object it receives as an argument.

While this won't work for your example (because the objects in `ENV` don't respond to `:bar`), you can pass a block that's been stored in a variable by using `&`:

```
block = lambda { |key, value| puts "#{key}: #{value}" }
ENV.each(&block)
```